# Format text after using scripting dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I have a for loop that is printing the memory stored in its scripting dictionary. Once that is printed onto the excel sheet, I am wanting to format the text. I have the scripting dictionary code and the formatting code already made, but I am not sure how to combine the two together. I was originally thinking of creating it as a separate function (it may be used for formatting cells later on) but Im not experienced enough how to break it up that way. I have attached my scripting dictionary code and formatting code below.

```
                For Each key In dict
            
                .Cells(DonutType, Column_B).Value = vbNewLine & key & " - " & dict(key)
                DonutType = DonutType + 1 'Go to next row

                Next key
```

Formatting code is shown below:

```
                arr = Split(.Cells(DonutType, Column_B).Value, Chr(10)) ' Spliting cell contents by newline character
                
                pos = 1
                For line = 1 To UBound(arr) + 1
                    
                    txt = arr(line - 1)
                    length = Len(txt)
                
                    'check which line we're on...
                    Select Case line
                        Case 2 'Bold and Italic on line 2
                            .Characters(pos, length).Font.Bold = True
                            dashPos = InStr(txt, "-")
                            .Cells(DonutType, Column_B).Value.Characters(pos + dashPos, length - dashPos).Font.Italic = True
                        Case 3: 'Bold on line 3
                            .Cells(DonutType, Column_B).Value.Characters(pos, length).Font.Bold = True
                        Case 4: 'Underline on line 4
                            .Cells(DonutType, Column_B).Value.Characters(pos, length).Font.Underline = True
                        Case 6: 'Underline on line 6
                            .Cells(DonutType, Column_B).Value.Characters(pos, length).Font.Underline = True
                    End Select
```

Comment: Didn't you post similar Q here? Different username but same code... 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896436/how-do-you-underline-bold-and-italicized-certain-portions-of-text-within-a-rang/65897082#65897082

Comment: Wrap the formatting code in a sub with a rang parameter - pass the cell which needs formatting to the sub when you call it.